# sports.util.Utils.openNewWindow is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, extjs, extjs4

- I have showNewWindow, showNewWindowSuccess functions in one js file
  and I have openNewWindow function in another js file,
- I am trying tto remove the showNewWindowSuccess function from my
  success function
- but I am getting the following error, Uncaught TypeError:
  sports.util.Utils.openNewWindow is not a function
- can you guys tell me how to fix it
- providing my code below

```
showNewWindow: function(menu) {
    var me = this,
        newWindowId = sports.util.Utils.randomString(12);
```

Comment: Not enough information, you need to post a test case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To declare a function in javascript you need this sintax:

```
function openNewWindow(param1, param2, param3){

          //Do something here...

         };
```